# Как сохранить файл содержащий "/" (слэш) Python

Tags: python, строки, файлы

Всем добрый день!
Есть, например, такая ссылка на статью: lenta.ru/news/2020/02/21/prosto/
Нужно сохранить текстовый файл, чтобы его название было идентично названию ссылки.

делаю этот так:

```
with open('lenta.ru/news/2020/02/21/prosto/.txt', 'w') as fl:
    fl.print(info)
```

Файла в директории нет, он должен создаваться автоматически,
но получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Питон/Задание в Тензор/mini_readability.py", line 17, in <module>
    with open(r'lenta.ru/news/2020/02/21/prosto/.txt', 'w') as fl:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lenta.ru/news/2020/02/21/prosto/.txt'
```

P.S. файл с именем, не содержащим слэш создаётся нормально
Спасибо!

Comment: для этого вам придется "хакнуть" операционную систему)

Comment: замените слеш на € и сохраняйте. при чтении патом обратно поменяете

Comment: советую как вариант решения заменить / на другой символ, к примеру _

Answer (score 4):

Так делать нельзя, имя файла не может содержать определённые знаки:

[image: так нельзя]

Comment: и хворостинкой по пальцам за непослушание

Answer (score 0):

```
def save(file, filename): 
    dirname = filename.replace('/', '!$!') #Вместо '!$!' можно поставить что-угодно, главное чтобы ОС не ругалась
    with open(dirname, 'w') as f:
        f.write(file)

def load(filename):
    dirname = filename.replace('/', '!$!')
    with open(dirname) as f:
        return f.read()
```